# Append data to field in object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, append

I am trying to append data in field using javascript.

I have this object :

```
{
  id: 1,
  time: 12:10:09,
}
```

and I have this date : 2021-12-01

I want to append this date to time.

object after append :

```
{
  id: 1,
  time: 2021-12-01 12:10:09,
}

date (space) time.
```

I tried:

```
object.time = date + " " + object.time;
```

but I don't think this is the best solution

Any suggestion?

Comment: `obj.time = new Date(\`${date}T${obj.time}\`).getTime()` is likely better

Comment: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' , type of time is string but we use .getTime() of type number. @mplungjan

Comment: then use obj.time = `new Date(\`${date}T${obj.time}\`).toISOString()`

Comment: Also how should I know your date cannot be a number. You did not flag TS

Comment: number include ':' ? anw thank you work fine. @mplungjan

Comment: `time: 12:10:09,` is an invalid string anyway. Also JS without TypeScript can re-assign a number to a string and vice versa